# hydro openni apt-get problem

Tags: openni, ros-hydro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to install the hydro turtlebot simulator on Ubuntu 12.04 (32 bit) but the dependencies for openni seem a bit wacky. I've installed and uninstalled a few times now and nothing seems to work. It seems to boil down to ros-hydro-openni-launch refuses to install because it doesn't want to install ros-hydro-openni-camera *even if ros-hydro-openni-camera is already installed.*

```
...
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ros-hydro-turtlebot-bringup : Depends: ros-hydro-openni-launch but it is not going to be installed
...
 ros-hydro-openni-launch : Depends: ros-hydro-openni-camera but it is not going to be installed
...
ros-hydro-openni-camera is already the newest version.
```

If I have ros-hydro-openni-camera installed, and then do an "apt-get install ros-hydro-desktop-full", it removes ros-hydro-openni-camera, e.g.

```
Removing ros-hydro-openni-camera ...
Removing libopenni-dev ...
Removing libopenni-sensor-primesense-dev ...
Removing libopenni-sensor-primesense0 ...
Removing openni-utils ...
Removing libopenni0 ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin ...
ldconfig deferred processing now taking place
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Selecting previously unselected package openni-dev.
```

...and I'm back at square one.

I'm guessing there's a conflict between **openni-dev** and **libopenni-dev**
Any suggestions as to how to get things installed properly?

Thanks,
-Mark

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/76495/hydro-openni-apt-get-problem/) by [mallanmba](https://answers.ros.org/users/6388/mallanmba/) on ROS Answers with karma: 46 on 2013-09-04

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thanks, all looks good now. For those who were experiencing this problem, do the following:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

...then install your ros debs

---

Originally posted by [mallanmba](https://answers.ros.org/users/6388/mallanmba/) with karma: 46 on 2013-09-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2013-09-05**:
Please accept the answer so people know your problem is solved.

**Comment by [pmolina](https://answers.ros.org/users/2919/pmolina/) on 2014-01-30**:
this did not really worked for me. Please check my problem http://answers.ros.org/question/115546/cannot-install-ros-hydro-on-ubuntu-1204/